# create image dynamically - PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I create an image dynamically using PHP GD. thus when I execute index.php it create image.png but I want image in index.php for example I can use `<img src="index.php">`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010742/image-processing-and-output-using-gd-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set header content-type to `header('content-type: image/jpeg');`
I have implemented a similar code once for a captcha

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
$string = "Type Me";
$im     = imagecreatefrompng(IMAGEDIR."captcha.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 5, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```